# Upgraded to 1.4.1 and now: Argument 'SearchPopover' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

First I had to fix the following:

```
controller: SearchPopover
```

Changed to

```
controller: 'SearchPopover as spop',
```

My Directive & Controller below, I've tried:
`.module('searchPopoverDirectives', ['searchPopoverDirectives.SearchPopover'])` but then I get an undetailed error `Uncaught Error:`

```
(function() { "use strict";

angular
    .module('searchPopoverDirectives', [])
    .directive('searchPopover', directive);

function directive() {
    var directive = {
        templateUrl : 'popovers/searchPopover/searchPopover.html',
        restrict: "E",
        replace: false,
        bindToController: true,
        controller: 'SearchPopover as spop',
        // controllerAs: 'spop',
        link: link,
        scope: {}
    };
    return directive;
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {}
}

SearchPopover.$inject = [
    '$scope',
    '$rootScope',
    '$timeout',
    'ApiFactory',
    'ScopeFactory',
    'TagFactory',
    'TickersSelectFactory',
    'TagDetailsFactory',
    'ViewFactory'];

function SearchPopover(
    $scope,
    $rootScope,
    $timeout,
    ApiFactory,
    ScopeFactory,
    TagFactory,
    TickersSelectFactory,
    TagDetailsFactory,
    ViewFactory) {
```

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="SearchPopover" ng-class="{'display-on': searchPopoverDisplay}" class="search-popover">
    ....
```

Comment: You would need to register the controller

Comment: @PSL could you provide a simple example please?

Comment: `moduleName.controller('SearchPopover', SearchPopover)`. Side note: I am not sure if the directive (1.4+) has started supporting `'SearchPopover as spop'` apart from controllerAs property

Comment: @PSL Thanks! That was it :) now time to fix my markup, do you want to post the answer?